# How to import Nagios config to Sensu?

Tags: monitoring, nagios, sensu

I have nagios config and Sensu test environment. And I want to add all nagios check to Sensu. Should I convert nagios configs to JSON or there are any solution, probably plugin for Sensu?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The check format is completely different for Sensu and Nagios. The scripts are the same, but the check *definitions* differ completely.

If you're hand crafting JSON, it's going to be quite painful. I would highly recommend investing in a configuration management tool like Puppet, Chef or Ansible to manage the check configurations for you programmatically.